# Can "La Corrida" mean "The Bullfight"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I am working on a product branding project and hope to use a Spanish term for a product line named after the Spanish form of bull fighting. Almost all the branding content will be in English so I just need to make sure the Spanish inspired product name is correct.

Google translate has "Bullfight" translated to "Corrida" and "The Bullfight" translated to "la corrida de toros".

But for this branding project, "Corrida" is too short and "la corrida de toros" is too long. "La Corrida" would be perfect but is this a good translation of The Bullfight? My research suggests the meaning is accurate but it might be a bad name.

Things I tried:

- The [Spanish Wikipedia entry for bullfighting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrida_de_toros) seems to use "corrida de toros" and never just "corrida". This suggests "la corrida de toros" would be required.
- A [Spanish dictionary](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/corrida) uses "corrida" alone to refer to a bullfight. But it also has orgasm as a possible meaning. Is "La Corrida" a terrible product name because of this?
- An [alternative online translation tool DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/la%20corrida) has "la corrida" translated as "the bullfight"

Comment: Do you plan to sell your product in Spain, Latin America, the Philippines, or anywhere in the US that has a significant Latino population? If not you might as well [follow the Japanese rule and name the product the way you want](https://www.forbes.com/sites/peterlyon/2017/12/28/car-names-that-raise-foreign-eyebrows-lost-in-translation-in-japan/?sh=7bf32d7bad55). If you are planning to sell to native Spanish speakers (rather than providing them with a free laugh), I suggest that you work with a native Spanish-speaking marketing person.

Comment: To add to the existing answers, _corrida_ is difficult to pronounce for non Spanish speakers, since the "RR" sound is quite hard. If you want to get something related to the bullfighting, you can browse through [a very long list of terminology terms](https://tauromaquia.jcyl.es/web/es/informacion-interes/glosario-terminos-taurinos.html). Also note that bullfighting is an activity with some supporters and a lot of detractors, so using this topic to target Spanish audiences may mean encountering people having strong opinions of the product no matter if they have even tried it.

Comment: I fully agree with @fedorqui. It is not easy to pronounce by English speakers and it is an activity with less and less supporters every day. Terrible idea. If you share more about the product you may get better feedback or even new ideas for the name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your product is going to be marketed in Spain I strongly recommend you don't name it that way as "una/la corrida" is slang for ejaculation.
(Plus half of the country is regularly against bullfighting in recent surveys).
That said, if it's *not* going to be marketed in Spain then...go for it I guess.

Comment: You are righ, but what is your alternative title?

Comment: Does "Corrida" or "Corrida de Toros" also have that slang double meaning? Maybe I could just drop the "La."

Comment: I'd say this is the right answer, and yes, "corrida" **will** still have that double meaning regardless. I'd argue dropping "La" will make little to no difference. If your product has nothing to do with bullfighting or orgasms, or any combination of those two, go for it at your own risk

Comment: I would recommend something like "La lidia" or maybe "Fiesta", if you want to follow the bullfighting path.

Comment: @Hermes thanks for the recs. What about La Plaza de Toros? I think this means The Bullring. Does it have any double meanings?

Comment: @Trindaz It can come up in conversation as a comedic metaphor about sex, but it is not often used in that sense. Really, I think there are very few things in Spanish that can't come up as a comedic metaphor about sex. In addition I have to say that "Corrida" years ago had a meaning much less loaded with sexual connotations, so it could be used in a literary context of the mid-twentieth century, for example.

Comment: @Trindaz I've never heard "la plaza de toros" be used on a sexual context. "Lidia" sounds better as a name, though, like Hermes proposed before. "Corrida" sounds very sexual however you phrase it (unless "de toros" follows it).

Comment: A normal joke in Spain is " a) donde esté una buena corrida que se quite el fútbol; b) ¡anda! y los toros..."

Answer (score 8):

Never use "La Corrida" even when you talking about Bullfighting. Here we use "Corrida de Toros". "Corrida" has a very strong sexual meaning.

I recommned you to use another word. If you product is related to bullfighting, you should use another word related to this "activity".

Answer (score 6):

As you has viewed, "La corrida" is the correct form to translate "The bullfight".

It's true that there's another acceptions with different meanings, but you can go ahead: your title is ok.

One example:

[image]

Comment: Good example image.

Answer (score 3):

> Depending on the use of this product and the environment

in which it will be sold and used, you may be able to use it. But don't get complicated. Try to focus your product not on the spectacle of the bull, but on the bull, avoid mixing terms that can be obviously misinterpreted or taken out of context.

But be careful, this could help your product to gain popularity, if I were to see it in a shop like "La corrida", I would surely take a picture to send it to my friends or upload it on Twitter. Also watch out for inappropriate names, it can be considered rude. As I said before, it all depends on the environment where you sell it.

Answer (score 3):

Better use this word: **FAENA**
Because, if you use the phrase: "La corrida" this phrase is misunderstood as: "ejaculate" in colloquial language; Spanish slang.

If it is aimed at a Spanish-speaking audience, it would be appropriate to use the word: **"FAENA"**

Wikipedia says this about it:
In bullfighting it is called task ("FAENA") in a general sense to the exercise that the right-hander does, being it better and more lucid, when it better executes the respective luck that bullfighting consists of. In the strictest sense, it is the fight that, passing from a crutch, the matador executes, before stabbing the bull.

Or use: La corrida de toros.

Or better than all, here in mexico we call it: **"La fiesta brava"** Or **"Fiesta Taurina"** Check those terms in google and you will notice that they are widely used in everyday language.

Comment: I don't like bullfighting very much but your suggestion "Fiesta Brava" sounds pretty good. Better than "Faena".